# How can I decrypt ClickBank notification data using PHP without mcrypt?

Tags: php, mcrypt, php-openssl, clickbank

Mcrypt has been deprecated for years and is finally gone from php.  Unfortunately I need to decode encrypted data from ClickBank and their documentation only offers mcrypt solutions.

This is cut from their documentation.  How can I do this without mcrypt_decode()?

```
$secretKey = "YOUR SECRET KEY"; // secret key from your ClickBank account

// get JSON from raw body...
$message = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// Pull out the encrypted notification and the initialization vector for
// AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding decryption
$encrypted = $message->{'notification'};
$iv        = $message->{'iv'};
error_log("IV: $iv");

// decrypt the body...
$decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                             substr(sha1($secretKey), 0, 32),
                             base64_decode($encrypted),
                             MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                             base64_decode($iv)), "\0..\32");
error_log("Decrypted: $decrypted");

////UTF8 Encoding, remove escape back slashes, and convert the decrypted string to a JSON object...
$sanitizedData = utf8_encode(stripslashes($decrypted));
$order         = json_decode($decrypted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$notification_array = json_decode(utf8_encode(stripslashes(trim(openssl_decrypt($encrypted,
                                 'AES-256-CBC',
                                 substr(sha1($secretKey), 0, 32),
                                 OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, base64_decode($iv)), "\0..\32"))), true);
```

Comment: Ah, there we go. "*ClickBank uses the CBC-AES-256*". Good mention.